# Fade out animation with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that attempts to demonstrate and animate a dequeuing procedure of an aircraft takeoff queue.
For every takeoff (or dequeue) which happens after 5 seconds, a box is supposed to fade out until all have faded out after the takeoff queue is empty.
My problem is how do i link each plane dequeue to a box such that for every dequeue a box fades out?

Here is the code snipet

```js
function airport() {
  this.takeoff_queue = ["KQA", "ERJ", "TOM", "DHL", "ETH"];
  this.landing_queue = ["RWA", "KLM", "PAN", "FLY540", "JAMBO"];
  console.log('DEPARTING', this.landing_queue, 'ARRIVING', this.takeoff_queue);
}
var departure = new airport();
var takeoff_interval = setInterval(function depart() {
  $("#box1").fadeOut();
  if (departure.takeoff_queue.length != 0) {
    departure.takeoff_queue.shift()
    $("#box1").fadeOut();
    console.log('DEPARTING', departure.takeoff_queue);
  } else {
    clearInterval(takeoff_interval);
    console.log('TAKEOFFS COMPLETE');
  }
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>SIMPLE SIMULATED TAKEOFF</h3>
<div id="box1" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background:black;float:left;margin:10px"></div>
<div id="box2" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background:black;float:left;margin:10px"></div>
<div id="box3" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background:black;float:left;margin:10px"></div>
<div id="box4" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background:black;float:left;margin:10px"></div>
<div id="box5" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background:black;float:left;margin:10px"></div>
```

If this is a wrong approach kindly explain it to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about associating each element with some data such as its destination in this case, and look for the element based on that

```js
function airport() {
  this.takeoff_queue = ["KQA", "ERJ", "TOM", "DHL", "ETH"];
  this.landing_queue = ["RWA", "KLM", "PAN", "FLY540", "JAMBO"];
  console.log('DEPARTING', this.landing_queue, 'ARRIVING', this.takeoff_queue);
}
var departure = new airport();
var takeoff_interval = setInterval(function depart() {
  if (departure.takeoff_queue.length != 0) {
    var dest = departure.takeoff_queue.shift()
    $("[data-dest='" + dest + "']").fadeOut();
    console.log('DEPARTING', departure.takeoff_queue);
  } else {
    clearInterval(takeoff_interval);
    console.log('TAKEOFFS COMPLETE');
  }
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>SIMPLE SIMULATED TAKEOFF</h3>
<div id="box1" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background:black;float:left;margin:10px" data-dest="KQA"></div>
<div id="box2" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background:black;float:left;margin:10px" data-dest="ERJ"></div>
<div id="box3" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background:black;float:left;margin:10px" data-dest="TOM"></div>
<div id="box4" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background:black;float:left;margin:10px" data-dest="DHL"></div>
<div id="box5" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background:black;float:left;margin:10px" data-dest="ETH"></div>
```

Comment: Associating each element with some data is quite insightful as it will also help me when i animate the other part covering the landing queue. Thanks very much. I hope to get your assistance if i get stuck :)

Answer (score 1):

Within your setInterval call, you're continually fading `#div1` which only should be faded once. I believe what you're after is `$("div:visible:first").fadeOut();`:

```
var takeoff_interval = setInterval(function depart() {
    if (departure.takeoff_queue.length != 0) {
        departure.takeoff_queue.shift()
        $("div:visible:first").fadeOut();
        console.log('DEPARTING', departure.takeoff_queue);
    } else {
        clearInterval(takeoff_interval);
        console.log('TAKEOFFS COMPLETE');
    }
}, 5000);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pdemz4z2/)**

Comment: This solves the immediate problem. Thanks a lot Sir!!

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue)

```js
function airport() {
  this.takeoff_queue = ["KQA", "ERJ", "TOM", "DHL", "ETH"];
  this.landing_queue = ["RWA", "KLM", "PAN", "FLY540", "JAMBO"];
  console.log('DEPARTING', this.landing_queue, 'ARRIVING', this.takeoff_queue);
}
var departure = new airport();

$(document).queue("q", $.map(departure.takeoff_queue, function(val, key) {
  // add `class` `departure.takeoff_queue` value to `div`
  $("div[id^=box]").eq(key).addClass(val);
  return function(next) {
    // select `div` by `departure.takeoff_queue` value `class`
    $("div[class="+val+"]").delay(5000).fadeOut(0, function() {
      console.log("DEPARTING:" + this.className);
      next()
    })
  }
})).dequeue("q").promise("q").done(function() {
  console.log("TAKEOFFS COMPLETE")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>SIMPLE SIMULATED TAKEOFF</h3>
<div id="box1" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background:black;float:left;margin:10px"></div>
<div id="box2" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background:black;float:left;margin:10px"></div>
<div id="box3" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background:black;float:left;margin:10px"></div>
<div id="box4" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background:black;float:left;margin:10px"></div>
<div id="box5" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background:black;float:left;margin:10px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks  for this assistance. i however do not understand it quite fully since i am just venturing into using JQuery more.